# python version 3.11.3 installation

Tags: python-3.11

iam trying to install pip install Package but my pc is not working anyone can resolve my issue
and it showing ######"C:\Users\91703>pip install virtualenv
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" install virtualenv': The system cannot find the file specified."#####. and iam successfully configured python path location in user and system variables also installed pip package in my command prompt....

need solution for my issue its suffering me a lot

Comment: try to remove the "old" python first

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the old python
2. Download at the [official website](https://www.python.org/) and install it
3. Run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` in cmd
4. Run `pip install virtualenv` in cmd

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog post related to your problem, maybe [check it out](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-winerror-2-system-cannot-find-file-specified)